# how to store my iterations into arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've defined the following function which takes x and n as arguments, using Taylor series summation to approximate arctan. I also embedded a conditional statement inside so the function works for all x.
import math

```
import math

for x in range(1,10,1):
   def arctan(x, n):
       arctang=0
       inv_x=1/x
       for i in range(n):
        sign=(-1)**i
        arctang = arctang + ((inv_x**(2.0*i+1))/(2.0*i+1))*sign

       if x>0:
        arc_tan=(math.pi/2)-arctang

       else:
           arc_tan=-(math.pi/2)-arctang

       return arc_tan


   print(arctan(x,100))
```

this code prints the iterations:

0.7878981009052581

1.1071487177940906

1.2490457723982544

1.3258176636680326

1.3734007669450157

1.4056476493802696

1.4288992721907325

1.446441332248135

1.460139105621001

however I want to be able to store the x values into an array, and these iterations into another so I can generate a graph out of the arrays, ie:
something along the lines x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] y=[iterations as listed]

How should I go about doing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize an empty array of *xmap* and *ymap* and then try to `append` in that. A sample code would look like:

```
xmap = []
xmap.append(str(x))
```

Similarly for *y*.

```
ymap = []
ymap.append(str(arctan(x,100)))
```

Don't forget to initialize the `xmap` and `ymap` outside of the loop. If you want me to modify the whole of your code then let me know.

**Update**
Complete code in 1D array.

```
import math
xmap = []
ymap = []

for x in range(1,10,1):
   def arctan(x, n):
       arctang=0
       inv_x=1/x
       for i in range(n):
        sign=(-1)**i
        arctang = arctang + ((inv_x**(2.0*i+1))/(2.0*i+1))*sign

       if x>0:
        arc_tan=(math.pi/2)-arctang

       else:
           arc_tan=-(math.pi/2)-arctang

       return arc_tan
   xmap.append(str(x))
   ymap.append(str(arctan(x,100)))

x = xmap
y = ymap
print "x= ",x
print "y= ",y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) I've tried the following code:xmap = []
xmap.append(str(x))

ymap = []
ymap.append(str(arctan(x,100)))

print(xmap, ymap), but it only returns a 1-d array....please could you modify my code for me if it's no trouble?

Comment: Yeah sure! I can modify the code. But can you please tell me what is your expected output. Because from your question what I can understand is that it is in 1D array.

Comment: thanks prashant i think that's done the trick! I just changed the data type to float as wanna output  1d arrays of x and y so can plot them against eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Don't redefine the function in every iteration. This way you will be able to use list comprehension in order to create the "iterations" list.

```
import math

def arctan(x, n):
       arctang = 0
       inv_x = 1/x
       for i in range(n):
        sign=(-1) ** i
        arctang = arctang + ((inv_x ** (2.0 * i + 1)) / (2.0 * i+1)) * sign

       if x>0:
        arc_tan = (math.pi / 2) - arctang

       else:
           arc_tan = -(math.pi / 2) - arctang

       return arc_tan

iterations = [arctan(x, 100) for x in range(1, 10, 1)]
```

You can change the comprehension to also store the value of `x`, then each element of the `iterations` list will be a tuple:

```
iterations = [(x, arctan(x, 100)) for x in range(1, 10, 1)]
```

By the way, `numpy` already has an `arctan` function: [`numpy.arctan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not vectorize `arctan()` itself?

```
def varctan(x, n):
    inv_x = 1/x

    signs = numpy.empty((len(x), n))
    signs[:, ::2] = 1
    signs[:, 1::2] = -1

    exprange = 2.0 * numpy.arange(n)[None, :] + 1
    signs *= (inv_x[:, None] ** exprange) / (exprange)
    arctang = numpy.sum(signs, axis=1)

    arctang *= -1
    arctang[x > 0] += numpy.pi / 2
    arctang[~x > 0] -= numpy.pi / 2

    return arctang

varctan(numpy.arange(1, 10), 100)
```